# How to append text in d3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I am trying to add text in force layout. First i am creating a svg group and i am appending circle and text into it. The circle is working fine but the text is not working. Here is the code

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g")
                    .data(measures.nodes)
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .call(node_drag);
var circle = node.append("circle")
                    .attr("fill", "blue")
                    .attr("r",5)
                    .attr("dx", ".10em")
                    .attr("dy", ".10em");

var text = node.append("text")
                .data(measures.nodes)
                .attr("color", "blue")
                .text(function(d){ return d.name; })
```

Comment: Can you create something runnable, a jsfiddle or stack snippet?

Comment: here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/6n0vd4nb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is of the screen because you've missed out the positioning methods. If you add this you'll see [text attached to the nodes](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/6n0vd4nb/2/).

```
        text.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
```